# why do electrical wires coil over time?

Tags: cables

I've dealt with multiple electrical cables both 120 extension cords and laptop low voltage cords that when the cable is new it's straight (as in you can reasonably pull it fairly straight without trouble)
but over time it forms this weird coiling shape almost as if it's wrapped around the length of a thin rod with roughly a turn of wire around said rod being every few inches ... come to think of it maybe the shape would better be called a spiral? or helix? anyways does anyone know why this seems to happen with so many electrical cables?

Comment: Because people don't listen to what the cable is telling them while rolling it and force it to coil up inside. With every turn you make, you have to release the cable's inside tension. Either that or stop coiling up the cable. There are several methods to stop torturing cables, here is one video on that topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpuutP6Df84

Comment: Bundled cables have less problem than layered ones. Layered cables are cheap because the conductors are circularly placed around the core. But then the conductors shift/compress readily to release torsional stress. Bundled cables have inner strength and are more stable. Core design/jackets can help. The stronger and more tensile the core and/or having a reinforced jacket firmly holding the cable together can help maintain the cable. You can also coil up cables using a special, alternating right/left looping arrangement, too, and this can help avoid the trouble in cheaper cables.

Comment: This does not happen to me.

Comment: It is because you have not learned how to properly coil cables, or someone else who has not learned is coiling your cables.

Comment: @jippie - I spent some time on a Tall Ship (the Kalmar Nyckel), and learned how to coil both stranded and unstranded lines.  One method that I use on anything that doesn't have a natural twist is called an 'alternating hitch coil', where you first make sure no twist is in your line, and then you grab one coil length and twist it, then grab one coil length and twist it the reverse direction.  This allows the cable to twist and untwist with each 'turn'.  This is usually used for throwing/heaving lines aboard a ship, so they can be reliably tossed without kinking

Comment: @Cinderhaze That used to be called "flaking down" a rope. I also found on an abseiling course recently that climbing ropes are also flaked alternately left and right, but the middle of each coil is laid into your hand as you go.

Comment: 'flaking down' would be putting the line on the deck, so it could run (for a heavy dock line), but the alternating left and right in your hand matches what I described!

Answer (score 12):

That happens because of the way most folks coil the extension cord.

If you "roll" it up around your arm, you twist the cable as you coil it around your arm.  Every time you coil it up, the twist gets worse.

If you have an extension cord reel, then you won't get a twisted cord.

You have two options to avoid twisting your extension cords:

1. Use an extension cord reel to roll up and store your extension cords.
2. Alternate from which end you coil the extension cord if you coil over your arm.  Roll it up one time from the plug end, and the next time from the other end.  Swap ends every time you roll up the extension cord.

Comment: if not for my laptop low voltage cord doing the same time that explanation would make a lot of sense but I don't regularly role that cable up if I store it at all I do the fold it up like shoe laces come when you buy replacements so I'm left wondering why it happens to that cord as well?

Comment: @GokuGohan Folding a cable up like a shoelace can also twist the cable. Do you know how to coil or fold a cable so that it doesn't twist the cable? If you've never been taught that, then you will probably twist the cable every time you coil it (or fold it).

Comment: Another approach is to "roll up" the cord in a figure-8, then fold in half to make a loop once done.

Answer (score 8):

Electrical cables are extruded and very shortly thereafter coiled on a cable drum for storage and distribution. The insulation will still be somewhat warm and so the cable takes a "set" in the coiled shape. The strength of this set will depend on the level of plasticiser in the insulation (more makes the cable softer) and the temperature of use. The end result is a tendency to go back to the coiled shape.

The effect can be reduced by taking care to unwind by pulling it straight off the drum (or rotating the coil). Pulling the cable sideways off the drum or coil will result in the worst case.

Answer (score 4):

You are supposed to coil cables by holding the end in one hand and with the other hand grasp a segment that is one circumference length away from the end between your two fingers roll it so that it twists itself naturally into a coil without any containing any twisting stresses. The same way cowboys coil up their lasso rope. Important for scope probes which cost thousands and thousands of dollars. This is how you wind stress free coils of wire, rope, or string.

If you don't you are twisting the cable when you coil it up so when it uncoils it retains that twist. Grab a USB cable and try it. If it doesn't spool up cleanly or consistently it is because someone put a twist into it previously.

Comment: You then need to reverse this process uncoiling.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford I suppose you're right. I've never given it much thought since i automatically do it when I unwind it and its really easy to do since it was wound up without any internal stress. I suppose that's why in Cinderhaze's comment at the top they alternate the twist.

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you want so store the cable you are winding it but when you wnat to use the cable again you are probably not UNwinding it, just strech it open.